# Have created a database, and i am trying to connect it to my model and execute the SQL queries through the model only. What to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What the hell is wrong with this code? And how to run this code?
Please explain me little thoroughly as I am new to ruby. Please help!!!

## my_connection_base.rb

class MyConnectionBase < ActiveRecord::Base

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :database => "flipkart_project_development", :table  => "users" , :username => "flipkart_project", :password => "mypass")

results = client.query("SELECT * FROM users")

puts results

end

Comment: as it is, this question is unaswerable. Please provide more context, what are you trying to do, is this within a rails app (you tagged it rails)? As it stands this code makes very little sense. Maybe you should read some tutorial first...

Comment: I have read tutorials. Yeah this is a rails app. In this there is this model my_connection_base.rb and I have made a database called flipkart_project. I ran a query "SELECT * FROM users" on users table from this model and put it in results. I want to show the rows fetched in results. How to do that? I know about migration and stuff but i need to do this in the method i have done. Need your help!!

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you do not need to write a raw SQL queries.

Just put all your database configurations in config/database.yml file like below.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: flipkart_project_development
  username: flipkart_project
  password: yourpass
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: flipkart_project_test
  username: flipkart_project
  password: yourpass
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: flipkart_project_production
  username: flipkart_project
  password: yourpass
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Rails will take care of establishing connection and executing queries.

In your case generate a model named user

```
 rails g model user
```

In your project you can fetch all the users like below.

```
User.all
#This will generate the SQL query "select * from users" 
#and will return the records as user objects.
```

Take a look at [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) too.

Comment: :Thanks a lot for answering. But i know everything about migrations and  database.yml configurations. In case when i have given all the information about host, table, database etc. 

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :database => "flipkart_project_development", :table => "users" , :username => "flipkart_project", :password => "mypass")

Why cant it connect to the mentioned database and fetch the data for me using the query I have provide? Why?

Comment: Rails is built according to the principle of convention over configuration. In Rails, the convention is that you don't build your own queries. You can do it if you really want, but as a novice user you shouldn't. Just follow the convention. If you really want to do that, you'd better not use rails, and try something like Sinatra.

Answer (score 0):

The code as given would be difficult to execute on demand: it would be executed when the model was loaded. It should be placed in a method:

```
class MyConnectionBase < ActiveRecord::Base   
  def some_method
    client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :database => "flipkart_project_development", :table => "users" , :username => "flipkart_project", :password => "mypass")
    results = client.query("SELECT * FROM users")
    puts results
  end
end
```

This could then be called in your controllers with `MyConnectionBase.some_method`.
But why you would want to do this eludes me completely. It would be much better to do it all the Rails way (see my comment above).